# Move divs towards right side using flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How to give spacing between different divs, using flex box.
I want to move last 3 divs towards right side of screen, giving equal space between them

```css
.flexBox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 20px;
  font-family: myriad-pro, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.flexBox > div:nth-child(2),
.flexBox > div:nth-child(3),
.flexBox > div:nth-child(4) {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexBox">
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt=""></div>
  <div><a class="navbutton" href="https://google.com">Home</a></div>
  <div><a class="navbutton" href="https://google.com">FAQ</a></div>
  <div><a class="navbutton" href="https://google.com">Log in</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I rewrote your code removing `.THIS` before the `.flexbox` classed, why dit you put it ? And what about the result now ?

Answer (score 0):

The quick solution for you:

```
<div class="flexBox">
    <div class="logo-wrap"> <img src="{/logo.svg}"/> </div>
    <div><a class="navbutton" href="https://Google.com" >Home</a></div>
    <div><a class="navbutton" href="https://Google.com" >FAQ</a></div>
    <div><a class="navbutton" href="https://Google.com" >Log in</a></div>
</div>

<style>
    .flexBox {
        display:flex;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .logo-wrap {
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    .navbutton {
        padding: 0 10px;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions for this. The main takeaway is to group navigation items (links) within their own container.

```css
.flex {
  width: 600px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav__item {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav__item:not(last-of-type) {
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div> <img src="https://placehold.it/60x60"/> </div>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav__item"><a class="navbutton" href="https://Google.com" >Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav__item"><a class="navbutton" href="https://Google.com" >FAQ</a></li>
    <li class="nav__item"><a class="navbutton" href="https://Google.com" >Log in</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Note: if you don't care about the specific margin between navigation items, BUT let's say your navigation is 300px wide and you just want the items to be spaced equally:

```
.nav {
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav__item {
  // now you don't need any code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give `margin-right: auto` to the `.flexBox > div:first-child` to push the other siblings to the right, then just adjust the `margin` of the `.flexBox > div:nth-child(3)`, which is the middle one among the three, to achieve equal spacing between them:

```css
body {margin: 0}

.flexBox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 20px;
  font-family: myriad-pro, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  background: lightblue; /* demo */
}

.flexBox > div:first-child {
  margin-right: auto;
}

.flexBox > div:nth-child(3) {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

/* addition */
img {
  display: block; /* or "vertical-align: middle" removes bottom margin/whitespace */
}
```

```html
<div class="flexBox">
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt=""></div>
  <div><a class="navbutton" href="https://google.com">Home</a></div>
  <div><a class="navbutton" href="https://google.com">FAQ</a></div>
  <div><a class="navbutton" href="https://google.com">Log in</a></div>
</div>
```